# How to compare elements in a list without for loop?

Tags: python

I have a list: `R = ['123', '1854', '000']` and I want to make sure that all the elements on it have the same length, but I don't want to use a `for` loop.

I tried this:

```
if R[::] !== R[::]:
   print('false')
```

Obviously it does not work.

It's possible to do it without a `for` loop?

And How to put it as an AssertError like: `assert ..., 'False'`? if the list elements are length different then raise an AssertError.

Comment: With a while loop ? And why don't you wanna put a for loop ?

Comment: `len(set(len(i) for i in R)) == 1:` (untested)

Comment: @TheMachinist I don't want to add more lines in my code.

Comment: You could always make one function and call that function everytime?

Comment: @walid do you call list comprehensions for loops? If not, then it's easy.

Comment: Adding code is a fundamental concept of programming, isn't it?

Comment: `if len(set(map(len, R))) != 1: print(False)`

Comment: @AnnZen I don't understand what you meant

Comment: list comprehensions are like for-loops, but in a list

Comment: @DarrylG it works, one more thing is it possible to put as: `assert len(set(map(len, R))) != 1, 'False'`

Comment: @walid--you can have `assert len(set(map(len, R)))  == 1`, which will cause AssertionError with a Tracebak when it's != 1.

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you it works!

Comment: sorry @DarrylG, I also want to see if the elements are equal then return `False`, I tried: `assert list(map(list, R)) == 1, 'False'`, but it doesn't work, could you propose a solution pls?

Comment: @walid--are you saying rather than all having the same lengths you want to see if they are all equal?

Comment: @DarrylG Yes, I want to add another `assert` that satisfy if there are some elements equal then return `False`.

Comment: @walid--do you need all the elements to be equal or just some?  Meaning is [1, 1, 2] okay, since some are equal?  Or do you need all equal so [1, 1, 1] is okay?  Or are you looking for all elements to be unique such as [1, 2, 3]?

Comment: @DarrylG the first and the last ones is right, for example: if ['12', '12', '11'] or ['12', '12', '12']  raise error: `False`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214854/discussion-between-darrylg-and-walid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably make a function and call that, but you could do something like this

```
if len(set(map(len,R))) != 1:
    # Do something, there exists elements of different sizes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = any(map(lambda x: len(x) != len(R[0]), R))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the code returns the opposite of what I want: if the length of elements is different then print false.